# Solr - fq bases

Tags: caching, solr

Just some generic questions about Filter Queries on solr (fq):

1. Does a fq query cache all the potential results, or only the ones the query returns?

   e.g.: select?q=*:*&fq=bPublic:true&rows=10

   => with this query, if I have 60 millions of public documents, would it cache 10 or 60 millions of IDs?
2. does it cache different result for the 2 following queries? (may be replied by the first question...):

   - select?q=*:*&fq=bPublic:true&rows=10
   - select?q=field:my_search&fq=bPublic:true&rows=10   <=> ***assuming here it only returns some of the documents***
3. does the Solr cache the IDs from filter Query in the OS cache or in java heap?
4. Is the fq "executed" before or after the usual query (q)

   e.g.: select?title:"something really specific"&fq=bPublic:true&rows=10

   Would it first:

   - get all the "specific" results, and then apply the filter
   - OR is it first getting all the docs matching the fq and then running the "q" query

Thanks in advance.

kr,
Bast

Answer (score 0):

I got some answers from the solr mailing list:

1. & 2. It stores every document in the core, with a bit (1 or 0) to store if it's matching the query.
2. http://yonik.com/advanced-filter-caching-in-solr/ ==> fq queries are executed before the main q queries.